# Multiple resource packages with Swagger 2

Tags: java, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

Is there any way of specifying multiple packages when configuring Swagger 2?

```
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.company1.resources ; org.company2.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
```

`BeanConfig.setResourcePackage` only takes a String. If I separate them with a space, only the first one is considered. If I try with a [semicolon](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/LHtjPc058TU), swagger doesn't find any.

I have a Spring Boot application with Jersey 2.

Answer (score 6):

I have not seen this documented anywhere, but based on the code in the current Swagger core (1.5.10) it looks like you separate multiple packages by a comma (',').  Here is the relevant snippet from `BeanConfig.java`:

```
    if (resourcePackage != null && !"".equals(resourcePackage)) {
        String[] parts = resourcePackage.split(",");
        for (String pkg : parts) {
            if (!"".equals(pkg)) {
                acceptablePackages.add(pkg);
                config.addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(pkg));
            }
        }
    } else {
        allowAllPackages = true;
    }
```

Further down it appears the `allowAllPackages` flag causes Swagger to generate documentation on all classes in the application's classpath that have JAX-RS annotations.  Depending on what dependencies you have, simply not setting a resource package at all might be an option.  Probably safer to use the comma-separated list, though.

Edit:

I did find mention of this in the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#using-swaggers-beanconfig):

> setResourcePackage(String)
>
> resourcePackage
>
> Sets which package(s) Swagger should scan to pick up resources. If there's more than one package, it can be a list of comma-separated packages.

Answer (score 1):

If all the API are in same project but in different packages then You can give the name of the base package of both like this.

**com.company1.resources1  org.company1.resources2**
Then give only name of one like this- then it will List all Controllers.

```
  @Bean
        public Docket api() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                    .basePackage("com.company1"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
        }
```

Comment: I think you meant com.company1 for both resources1 and resources2, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet for swagger2:

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
  .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
```

This worked for me because it takes all the controller packeages and rest endpoints

Answer (score 0):

We can add multiple packages like below code snippet:

```
List<Predicate<RequestHandler>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
predicateList.add(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(com.sample.one));
predicateList.add(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(com.sample.two));

Docket d = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.or(predicateList))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().forCodeGeneration(true)
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(oAuthSecurityScheme()));
```

Comment: This can also be used :
.apis(Predicates.or(firstBasePackage(), secondBasePackage())